# Application configuration exposed via Web

Tags: c#, .net, http, frameworks

Hi guys I need to exposed my application configuration files that can be edited on the fly and some reports on a web page. All of my application are either console / win forms app.

I'm planning to use XSLT and http listener class of .net for the implementation is this a good idea to start or not? or is there any implementation of this kind ?

Answer (score 0):

Editing web.config or app.config should be avoided in lieu of storing such settings that need to change dynamically in another data store, like a database.  If you store such settings in a database you can easily create a UI to administer such settings.

Comment: Thanks for suggesting that the configuration can reside on a database. What I'm thinking is to used xslt so that any browser that understand it will create a UI by itself. What I'm looking is , if there are other implementation besides my idea. I need to decide if using xslt is good enough so that I can share this with my team.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding you correctly then what you want is a web interface that users can use to modify some configuration properties and/or generate some reports based on data that is being used/generated by one or more desktop applications.

You need to define a central database, like SQL Server or something similar. Your desktop applications then need to store their data in this database. Then it would be super easy to build a web user interface that could also use the same database and view/manipulate data.

You're question is kind of vague so for now that's the best answer I can give you. I'm thinking you need to re-think your architecture.

Comment: Yes I need a web interface but per application. I've seen this kind of stuff. You can only access the web interface if the application hosting it is running.